# Java editing program to println directly to SWT text widget instead of console

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, swt

I have a java program that uses println to print a nicely formated 2d array. In eclipse, this array is of course printed to the console. However, I have made a seperate SWT program in the same project and I want to have this array printed to a text widget instead of the eclipse console. How do I do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(path);
        String[][] pf = file.aryData();
        int tmp = 1;
        int yn=1;
        while(yn==1){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("To View-0 , Add-1 ");
        yn = in.nextInt();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true)));
        out.println("");
        if (yn == 1) {
            String[][] newpf = new String[pf.length + 1][c];
            String newData1;
            System.arraycopy(pf, 0, newpf, 0, pf.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                System.out.print("Insert " + pf[0][i]+":     ");
                if (i==0){
                    in.nextLine();
                    newData1 = in.nextLine();
                    out.print(newData1);
                }   
                else { 
                    newData1 = in.nextLine();
                    out.print(", "+newData1);
                }   
                newpf[pf.length][i] = newData1;
            }
            System.out.print("");
            pf=newpf;
            out.close();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pf.length; i++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < c; k++) {
                int tmp2 = pf[i][k].length();
                if (tmp2 > tmp) {
                    tmp = tmp2 + 5;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pf.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                String fmStr = "%-" + tmp + "s";
                System.out.printf(fmStr, pf[i][j]);
            }  
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it prints to the console, does it use System.out directly ? you may have to parametrize the System.out as a PrintStream in order to use another PrintStream that will print to an OutputStream.

[EDIT after upload of code]

If i get what you want to do, you would have to replace the line "System.out.printf(fmStr, pf[i][j]);" to store the string or write the formated output to another stream and redirect it to your other program. You might want to externalize the treatment from the Main in order to use it in your SWT program.

Comment: If i get what you want to do, you would have to replace the line "System.out.printf(fmStr, pf[i][j]);" to store the string or write the formated output to another stream and redirect it to your other program.
You might want to externalize the treatment from the Main in order to use it in your SWT program.

Comment: I agree with this one. You might want to extract the array printing code to a method that takes an `OutputStream` (or a `PrintWriter`) as a parameter. This way, you can pretty print to console, `StringOutputStream`, whatever.